# Excel downloaded corrupted using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to download the Excel file using POI. The excel file is being downloaded as an attachment to the response. I referred to other questions present on Stack Overflow, and the answers there have been mainly to try out different Content Types, and I have tried all the different content types mentioned but still the Excel file downloaded is corrupt.

Also, when I tried to write the Excel on the file system using the same code(with just the change to write it to file system in place of returning as an attachment), the generated excel on the file system was properly created and was not corrupt. Only when I try to return it with HTTP response, the excel file gets corrupted.

Here is the code I am using for excel download:

**MainController.java**

```
if (downloadFlag) {
            response = reportsService.initializeXLSContent(response, "Tests_By_Day", fromDate, toDate);
            List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
            columnNames.add("Day");
            columnNames.add("Tests Count");
            populateAndDispatch(response, result, columnNames);
            return null;
        }
```

**initializeXLSContent method**

```
public HttpServletResponse initializeXLSContent(HttpServletResponse response, String fileName, Date startDate,
        Date endDate) {
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    StringBuilder reportName = new StringBuilder(fileName);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (null != startDate) {
        calendar.setTime(startDate);
        reportName = reportName.append("_" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "_" + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                + "_" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    if (null != endDate) {
        calendar.setTime(endDate);
        reportName = reportName.append("_" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "_" + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                + "_" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    reportName.append(".xlsx");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + reportName.toString());
    response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    return response;
}
```

**populateAndDispatch method**

```
private void populateAndDispatch(HttpServletResponse response, List<ChartData> chartData,
        List<String> columnNames) {
    List<ArrayList<String>> reportData = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (columnNames.size()) {
    case 2:
        twoColumnPopulate(chartData, reportData);
        break;
    case 3:
        threeColumnPopulate(chartData, reportData);
        break;
    }
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = reportsService.generateContentXLS(reportData, columnNames);
    response = reportsService.dispatchXLSContent(response, workbook);
```

**twoColumnPopulate method**

```
private void twoColumnPopulate(List<ChartData> chartData, List<ArrayList<String>> reportData) {
    for (ChartData rowData : chartData) {
        ArrayList<String> tempRowData = new ArrayList<>();
        tempRowData.add(rowData.getxData());
        tempRowData.add(rowData.getyData());
        reportData.add(tempRowData);
    }
}
```

**generateXLSContent method**

```
public XSSFWorkbook generateContentXLS(final List<ArrayList<String>> sheetData, List<String> columnNames) {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
        font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        style.setFont(font);
        int i = 0; // i is used to iterate over rows
        for (String columnName : columnNames) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i++);
            cell.setCellValue(columnName);
            cell.setCellStyle(style);
        }
        int j;
        int k = 1; // j is used to iterate over columns and k is used to count
                    // no.of rows
        for (ArrayList<String> rowData : sheetData) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(k++);
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                row.createCell(j).setCellValue(rowData.get(j));
            }
        }
        return workbook;
    }
```

**dispatchXLSContent method**

```
public HttpServletResponse dispatchXLSContent(HttpServletResponse response, XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    try {
        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        workbook.close();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        LOGGER.error("IOException occurred in dispatchXLSContent: ", ie);
    }
    return response;
}
```

1 interesting thing that I found was that, I created a sample API to test this excel download feature and it worked fine with the same setup, but not in this particular API of mine. Here is the code for that sample API.

```
public void testDownload(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("A");
    test.add("B");
    test.add("C");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell1 = headerRow.createCell(0);
    cell1.setCellValue("Header 1");
    Cell cell2 = headerRow.createCell(1);
    cell2.setCellValue("Header 2");
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Cell 1");
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Cell 2");
    row = sheet.createRow(1);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Cell 1");
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Cell 2");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=hello.xlsx");
    response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    workbook.close();
}
```

In this case, the Excel is not getting corrupted and is being downloaded properly.

Comment: Check you are closing the files, writers or streams, in our case these was the problem.

Comment: In my code I have closed the workbook and also tried closing the response's outputstream, both didn't work for me. And the thing is that the code is working fine if I write a file to filesystem. This code breaks only when I try to return the excel sheet with HTTP response